# SSIS data conversion loses extended ASCII

Tags: ssis, varchar, sql-server-2019, nvarchar

I'm reading from a data source that returns unicode strings, and the output goes into a data conversion transform where I output a "string [DT_STR]" from it as my database is using `varchar` and not `nvarchar`.

The source is outputting a string with an en dash in it, but after the conversion, my database ends up with â€“ in place of the en dash.

I know a varchar can contain an en dash character directly.  What's the proper way to handle this conversion without losing that en dash?

Comment: You kind of already answered it, make it nvarchar.

Comment: It also sounds like the source is t defined with the right code page.

Comment: But an en dash can be stored perfectly fine with a varchar.  It doesn't require an nvarchar to do so.  I can't just change the type of the column at this point. @Brad